# sqlite3 error installing Google Cloud SDK with multiple versions of py2.7

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

Moving from an AWS setup to GCE for the first time, so kindly bear with my naive questions.

During the step `./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh`, I encountered the following the error:

```
  Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/t/Desktop/./google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 8, in <module>
      import bootstrapping
    File "/Users/t/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 19, in <module>
      from googlecloudsdk.core.credentials import store as c_store
    File "/Users/t/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/store.py", line 34, in <module>
      from googlecloudsdk.core.credentials import creds
    File "/Users/t/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/creds.py", line 40, in <module>
      import sqlite3
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
      from dbapi2 import *
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 28, in <module>
      from _sqlite3 import *
  ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

Upon close inspection, I noticed that there were two python2.7 versions in my `/usr/local/Cellar/python` viz. `2.7.10_2` and `2.7.11`.

Strangely enough, when I go to python command line, this issue:

```
  Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07)
  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

  >>> import sqlite3
  >>> from _sqlite3 import *
  >>> print('hello, this seems to work')
      hello, this seems to work
```

While it is unfortunate that the `install.sh` is picking up `py2.7.11` version and not the python version from the System, I am not sure if we can set some environmental variables, (e.g. `$CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` before we start with installation).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should set your $CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to the correct Python installation. See a similar question: [google-cloud-sdk installation not finding right Python 2.7 version in CentOS /usr/local/bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064633/google-cloud-sdk-installation-not-finding-right-python-2-7-version-in-centos-us)

Comment: If anyone is running into this issue with asdf version manager, I was able to fix this by setting $CLOUDSDK_PYTHON to my system python at /usr/bin/python3.8

Answer (score 3):

I am using `pyenv` and install different python versions, and I have to configure `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` to point to the system python under `/usr/local/bin` to make it work.

Pointing to somewhere inside pyenv e.g `/home/user/.pyenv/shims/python` or `/home/user/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/bin/python2`
will not solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Hit this issue today and, since python2 has reached its end-of-life it's better to start using python3.

Here's a set of commands that's worked for me on CentOS 7:

Some important points:

- Install sqlite-devel package (the name may change depending on your distro)
- Pass --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions when configuring your Python interpreter
- Use `altinstall` so that you don't ruin `yum` on your host as it relies on python2 being the default interpreter

```
sudo yum install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel sqlite-devel
cd /usr/src
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.6/Python-3.8.6.tgz
sudo tar xzf Python-3.8.6.tgz
cd Python-3.8.6
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions
sudo make altinstall
sudo rm /usr/src/Python-3.8.6.tgz
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is The issue when while running installation link cloudsql is not able to find the executable python So to solve it I adopted this method

1. `which python`
   It will give the path of python something like usr/bin/python
2. make the symlink for the execution

   `ls -s usr/bin/python usr/local/bin/python`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment like if you are using oh-my-zsh -

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

and then -

```
source .zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oh-My-ZSH Plugin you need to manually edit your `.zshrc` file.

ADD the below line:

`export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3"`

Under:

`source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

Save your `.zshrc` file and restart your Shell to see the changes reflected.
[See below example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnywt.png)

Comment: Isn't this the same as the other answer?

Comment: @anton-krug 
Just `source .zshrc`  will only persist the change for that particular shell session.
Need to manually edit the `.zshrc` file for the changes to persist for every other shell sessions.

Comment: Oh, you are right. When you will have enough reputation then these are best put into the comments to existing answers/questions instead of making separate answers.